# error while persisting h2o mojo (version 3.20.0.1)

Tags: h2o

I've been having issue persisting mojos with latest h2o release. The code has been working fine for older version (3.10)

here is an example code and exception that is being thrown.

```
   public static Schema[] getAllSchemas() {
        ServiceLoader<Schema> schemaLoader = 
        ServiceLoader.load(Schema.class);
        List<Schema> allSchemas = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Schema schema : schemaLoader) {
            allSchemas.add(schema);
        }
        return allSchemas.toArray(new Schema[allSchemas.size()]);
   }

   public static byte[] extractIce(Model model) throws IOException {
       final UUID uuid = UUID.randomUUID();
       String tempFile = "/tmp/" + uuid;
       model.exportMojo(tempFile, true);
       final byte[] bytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(new 
                                   FileInputStream(tempFile)); 
       return bytes; 
    }


   public static void main (String []args) {
      H2OApp.main();
      SchemaServer.registerAllSchemasIfNecessary(getAllSchemas());
      // get the model that needs to be persisted
      // Model model = getH2OModel();
      byte[] extractIce(model);
   }
```

and this is the exception being thrown.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find Builder for algo url name drf
   at hex.ModelBuilder.ensureBuilderIndex(ModelBuilder.java:141) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at hex.ModelBuilder.havePojo(ModelBuilder.java:120) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at hex.Model.havePojo(Model.java:118) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at water.api.schemas3.ModelSchemaV3.fillFromImpl(ModelSchemaV3.java:73) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at water.api.schemas3.ModelSchemaV3.fillFromImpl(ModelSchemaV3.java:21) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at hex.ModelMojoWriter.writeModelDetails(ModelMojoWriter.java:277) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at hex.ModelMojoWriter.writeTo(ModelMojoWriter.java:178) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at hex.ModelMojoWriter.writeTo(ModelMojoWriter.java:169) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
   at hex.ModelMojoWriter.writeTo(ModelMojoWriter.java:161) ~[xyz-platform-all-7.9.0-SNAPSHOT.jar:7.9.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

Answer (score 1):

just in case someone runs in to same issue. I was able to persist mojos by calling following method (registerSchemasAndAlgos) right after H2OApp starts.

```
import hex.api.RegisterAlgos;
import water.api.RequestServer;
import water.api.Schema;
import water.api.SchemaServer;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;

public void registerSchemasAndAlgos() {
    // schemas
    SchemaServer.registerAllSchemasIfNecessary(getAllSchemas());

    // algos
    RegisterAlgos algos = new RegisterAlgos();
    algos.registerEndPoints(new RequestServer.DummyRestApiContext());
}

public void registerAlgos() {
    RegisterAlgos algos = new RegisterAlgos();
    algos.registerEndPoints(new RequestServer.DummyRestApiContext());
}

public Schema[] getAllSchemas() {
    ServiceLoader<Schema> schemaLoader = ServiceLoader.load(Schema.class);
    List<Schema> allSchemas = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Schema schema : schemaLoader) {
        allSchemas.add(schema);
    }
    return allSchemas.toArray(new Schema[allSchemas.size()]);
}
```